# Update the relevant counters (i.e., part, section, subsection, etc.) by adding tcolorbox to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

## Problem

I'm trying to add all of my `tcolorbox`es to my table of contents on the basis of their titles. So far, after looking at the [`tcolorbox` package documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/tcolorbox/0#page=132&zoom=100,94,56), this has worked pretty well with the use of an `auto counter` and the `number within` and `list inside` options.

However, the automatic numbering that is prepended to the ToC entry is off, in that the section numbering does not get updated by the addition of other `tcolorbox`es. I've attached a not-so-minimal working example to demonstrate this (sorry, I couldn't find the time to shorten it) and a picture.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

## Demonstrations

### Code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}

\usepackage[dvipsnames, cmyk]{xcolor}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, theorems}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=10pt,parsep=4pt,partopsep=0pt}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label={\scriptsize\raisebox{0.35ex}{$\blacksquare$}}}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\bullet$}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{10pt}
\addtolength{\cftsecindent}{10pt}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{10pt}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecindent}{10pt}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, colorlinks=false, linkcolor=black, pdfencoding=auto, pdfpagemode=UseNone]{hyperref}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\newlength{\tcolorboxtitleYshift}
\setlength{\tcolorboxtitleYshift}{0.5mm}
\newlength{\tcolorboxtitleXshift}
\setlength{\tcolorboxtitleXshift}{4mm}
\newlength{\tcolorboxtitleDepth}
\setlength{\tcolorboxtitleDepth}{1.5mm}

\colorlet{SummaryBoxTitleColour}{red!50!yellow}
\colorlet{SummaryBoxTitleColourShadow}{SummaryBoxTitleColour!30!black}
\colorlet{SummaryBoxBackColour}{red!10!white}
\colorlet{SummaryBoxRuleColour}{SummaryBoxTitleColour!80!black}

\colorlet{highmathColour}{NavyBlue!75!black}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{%
    enhanced,
    colback=SummaryBoxBackColour,
    colframe=SummaryBoxRuleColour,
    colbacktitle=SummaryBoxTitleColour,
    fonttitle=\Large\bfseries,
    arc=3.5mm,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=5mm,  % 1 + 4 mm
    right=5mm,  % 1 + 4 mm
    top=3mm,  % 1 + 2 mm
    bottom=3mm,  % 1 + 2 mm
    middle=3mm,  % 1 + 2 mm
    toptitle=1mm,  % 1 + 0 mm
    bottomtitle=1mm,  % 1 + 0 mm
    titlerule=1pt,
    titlerule style=red!50!black,
    varwidth boxed title={0.7\linewidth},
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=summaryboxes]{SummaryBox}[1][]{%
    sharp corners,
    rounded corners={southeast},
    frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-\tcolorboxtitleXshift, yshift=-\tcolorboxtitleYshift},
    varwidth boxed title={0.7\linewidth},
    add to list={toc}{subsection},
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=subsection, list inside=summaryboxes]{SummaryExtensionBox}[1][]{%
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=1pt,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift*={-\tcboxedtitleheight/2}},
    boxed title style={arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, boxrule=0.5mm,
                       frame code={ \fill[SummaryBoxRuleColour] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
                       -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
                       -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
                       interior code={ \fill[SummaryBoxTitleColour] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
                       -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
                       -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
                       -- cycle;} },
    add to list={toc}{subsubsection},
    #1
}

\title{\textbf{Test} --- \texttt{tcolorbox} and ToC}
\author{BrightBulb123}
\date{October 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\part{Test first part}

\section{Functions and relations}

\begin{SummaryBox}[title=Functions VS relations]
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item A \textbf{function} is a relation such that for each $x$-value there is only one corresponding $y$-value. This means that, if $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ are ordered pairs of a function, then $b=c$.
        \item In other words, a function cannot contain two different ordered pairs with the same first coordinate.
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{SummaryExtensionBox}[title=Types of functions (many/one-to-one)]
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item If $\forall a,b \in \dom(f): f(a) = f(b) \iff a = b$, or, to put it another way, $\forall a,b \in \dom(f): f(a) \neq f(b) \iff a \neq b$, then a function is a \textbf{one-to-one} function.
            \item A function that does not satisfy the above condition(s) is a \textbf{many-to-one} function.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{SummaryExtensionBox}
\end{SummaryBox}

\section{Still functions and relations}

\begin{SummaryBox}[title=Functions VS relations (second one)]
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item A \textbf{function} is a relation such that for each $x$-value there is only one corresponding $y$-value. This means that, if $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ are ordered pairs of a function, then $b=c$.
        \item In other words, a function cannot contain two different ordered pairs with the same first coordinate.
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{SummaryExtensionBox}[title=Types of functions (many/one-to-one) (also second one)]
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item If $\forall a,b \in \dom(f): f(a) = f(b) \iff a = b$, or, to put it another way, $\forall a,b \in \dom(f): f(a) \neq f(b) \iff a \neq b$, then a function is a \textbf{one-to-one} function.
            \item A function that does not satisfy the above condition(s) is a \textbf{many-to-one} function.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{SummaryExtensionBox}
\end{SummaryBox}

\end{document}
```

### Image

[image: Annotated image of the table of contents along with the tcolorboxes]

Comment: well you don't want `number within=subsection` for your section box, you don't have subsections yet. You want something like `auto counter, number within=tcb@cnt@SummaryBox,`. Or `use counter=subsection` in the outbox (which one depends on what you expect to happen if you have \subsection in your document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much for this!

`\newtcolorbox[use counter=subsection, number within=section, list inside=summaryboxes]{SummaryBox}[1][]{%` and `\newtcolorbox[use counter=subsubsection, number within=subsection, list inside=summaryboxes]{SummaryExtensionBox}[1][]{%` worked (with the rest of the code unchanged).

As per this, could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as such? Many thanks!